# Session works on localhost but not on ubuntu server(Servlet)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Here is the servlet code:

LoginServlet.java

```
@WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final String userID = "admin";
    private final String password = "password";

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // get request parameters for userID and password
        String user = request.getParameter("user");
        String pwd = request.getParameter("pwd");

        if(userID.equals(user) && password.equals(pwd)){
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("user", "Check");
            //setting session to expiry in 30 mins
            session.setMaxInactiveInterval(30*60);
            Cookie userName = new Cookie("user", user);
            userName.setMaxAge(30*60);
            response.addCookie(userName);
            response.sendRedirect("LoginSuccess.jsp");
        }else{
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp");
            PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
            out.println("<font color=red>Either user name or password is wrong.</font>");

            rd.include(request, response);
        }

    }

}
```

It works perfectly on my localhost, but when I upload it to Ubuntu server
it doesn't create session.

Comment: show us the complete exception stack trace. what do you mean `session` not created.

Comment: <form action="LoginServlet" method="post">

Username: <input type="text" name="user" value="admin">

Password: <input type="password" name="pwd" value="password">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form> 
Cant login. Password and username is right

Comment: I have 1 Ubuntu server. I am running multiple sites from that server using virtual domain.1 site is work perfectly and on the other site which i put the same project as the site 1 cant create session.So i made other project to to check the session is working or not.So above is the code for testing session project. I am in new in this area so please help me out.

Comment: i found that session is created but destroyed when click on the any pages link.

Comment: Do you get redirected to LoginSuccess.jsp? Explain the flow & errors you see in details. Check your tomcat logs for anything interesting.